# Find AUC for different cutoff values in R

Tags: r, logistic-regression, glm, roc, auc

I made a simple example. But, even when I changed the cutoff point, it seems like auc is still the same.

```
df<-data.frame(survived=c(1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,0,1,0,0,1,1,1,1,0,1),
                 math=c(90,100,23,34,56,22,34,78,90,55,67,87,34,25,46,47,34,78,90,54),
                 physics=c(100,23,34,56,67,89,65,43,56,78,99,87,65,43,23,23,24,34,78,30))

set.seed(101) 
sample <- sample.int(n = nrow(df), size = floor(.7*nrow(df)), replace = F)
train <- df[sample, ]
test  <- df[-sample, ]

glm.fit<-glm(survived~math+physics,family="binomial",data=train)


glm.probs<-predict(glm.fit,test,type="response")
glm.probs
glm.pred<-rep(0,nrow(test))
glm.pred[glm.probs>0.6]=1


library(ROCR)
pr <- prediction(glm.probs, test$survived)
auc <- performance(pr, measure = "auc")
auc <- auc@y.values[[1]]
auc
```

In the line `glm.pred[glm.probs>0.6]=1`, I used 0.6 as a cutoff value. However, I think this code is for calculating the auc for 0.5 as a cutoff value. I need some help.

Comment: You are  not using `glm.pred` in later code, only `glm.probs`. Therefore the AUC does not change. On top of that, the AUC calculation already accounts for different classification thresholds, there is no need to do it manually.

Comment: So, what I should change is `pr <- prediction(glm.pred, test$survived)`  istead of  `pr <- prediction(glm.probs, test$survived)` ?

Comment: What exactly do you want to achieve? The AUC is the area under the ROC curve. The ROC curve already takes into account different classification thresholds and calculates the false positive rate and true positive rate for each threshold. The AUC is a metric of your entire probabilistic model and is not linked to any specific threshold. You can do `plot(performance(pr,"tpr","fpr"))` to see the ROC curve.

Comment: Now I understood the concept of auc. I misunderstood the concept.

Comment: Understandable, it is not a simple concept. In my opinion Google has a nice explanation: https://developers.google.com/machine-learning/crash-course/classification/roc-and-auc